# Casperjs To publish a post in linkedin

Tags: javascript, iframe, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casperjs to login to linkedin and publish a post.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({

logLevel: "info",              // Only "info" level messages will be logged
verbose: true  ,               // log messages will be printed out to the console
 waitTimeout: 50000
});

casper.start('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login', function() {
this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function(term){
document.querySelector('input[id="session_key-login"]').setAttribute('value',term);
},'username');
casper.thenEvaluate(function(term){
document.querySelector('input[id="session_password-login"]').setAttribute('value',term);

},'password');

casper.then(function(){
this.click('input[name="signin"]');
console.log("clicking..........");
this.capture("linkedin.png");
});

casper.waitForSelector('a.publish', function() {
this.click('a.publish');

});
casper.waitForSelector('article.stream-article ', function() {
this.fillSelectors('article.stream-article',{
    'textarea.title':'This is title',
},false);

this.capture('linked3.png');

this.capture('linked4.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
this.sendKeys('textarea.title',"casper.page.event.key.Tab");

this.capture('linkedin5.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
this.fillSelectors('iframe[id^="editor-textarea"]',{
    'p':'This is title',
},false);
});

casper.run();
```

I am able to login and type the title of the post but i am not able to select the iframe and type the description of the post. Can anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this casper method `withFrame()`to access a frame, regarding to the latest version.

```js
  casper.open("http://www.example.com", function() {
    casper.withFrame('your-frame', function() {
      this.test.assertSelectorExists('#id-selector-inside-frame', 'Selector found');
    });
  });
```

The doc is here
http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe

Comment: But there is no name for the iframe. It has only a id.

<iframe id="editor-textarea-1443244730183_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 375px; display: block;"></iframe>

Comment: Yep, but according to the docs `withFrame` can handle an iframe by index. So if you find an apropriative index of the texteditor (in your case it will be 2), than you can use such code:
`casper.withFrame(2, function() { this.sendKeys('#tinymce', 'teeeeest');});`